# Clone / Copy Oracle 10g & 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-10g

Hi I am absolute begginer in Oracle domain. I would like to learn way how to clone copy oracle database to som backup, use this backup on another server.

Oracle is installed on Windows server 2003.

I have some question:

- When I need copy oracle DB I must shutdown service?
- I found many examples but I don’t know which is suitable for beginner.
- It exist som graphics Tool for cloning Oracle DB?

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to the world of Database Administration... and good luck. You're going to want to read up on as much Oracle documentation as you can, as well as other good technical sources (O'Reilly has always been good), and subscribe to lots of Oracle blogs.

I'll answer your questions here, but you're really going to want to get a solid foundation in RMAN ( For 10gR2: http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/portal.portal_db?selected=4 ).

1.Do you have to shutdown your Oracle DB when you want to make a copy/clone of it?

Yes and no. It depends on if your database is in *archivelog* mode. If the database is archiving its logs, the backup can be done while your database is online, though you may notice some performance degradation during the backup, so it is still a good idea to schedule the backup during a non-critical time of day. If the database is **not** archiving the logs, then you **must** shutdown the database *cleanly* in order to make a copy of it (any other way will result in a corrupt/incomplete restore).

2.A good beginner example

This is hard to do without knowing your environment. There are various RMAN commands that will happily clone a database on the same server, but when you get into moving a clone from one server to another, you have to go a different route. So without knowing your environment, I can't really tell you a good example.

That said, essentially your goal is to do the following: 
 - Get a good copy of all your datafiles
 - Get a good copy of all your archive logs
 - Get a good copy of your database parameters and control file
 - Create a new database with the settings from your old database (or reuse an existing database)
 - Copy over your datafiles and archive logs
 - Restore from your controlfile, and recover until there are no archives to process.

RMAN does a lot of the work for you with some fairly simple commands, so I suggest learning how to use it effectively, but you can always do the hard work without it. (For a long time at  a previous workplace, we did this with some shell scripts and such. Fun it was not, and was easy to screw up.)

3.Does a GUI exist for cloning an Oracle Database?

I think the thing that comes closest would be Oracle Enterprise Manager (GRID). It offers several automated backup/restore options as well as cloning features. Keep in mind, however, that it uses RMAN under-the-hood, and you should **never** use a tool blindly without understanding what's going on underneath. Sooner or later, you'll need to delve down into the command line because the GUI won't do what you want it to do, and without a good understanding, you'll be stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Just to supplement Kerri Shotts excellent answer<sup>(+1)</sup>, the Oracle documentation has an excellent guide on the steps required to duplicate a database.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmdupdb.htm#BRADV010

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to clone an Oracle database is with Delphix and Delphix is a graphical tool that can be used by a complete beginner. It's enterprise software so there is no free download for now, but I am working on getting a free download available, hopefully in the next year. For now I can give copies sometimes on an individual basis.

As an example of how easy it is, check out cloning a full Oracle RAC database in 5 minutes with out any RAC knowledge. RAC is complicated. Cloning RAC is complicated but with Delphix anyone can do it:
http://kylehailey.com/cloning-oracle-rac-in-5-minutes/

Again, full disclosure, I work at Delphix.

Still think its the coolest thing I've seen in years